# What can I read about permutations in 3D space?

Tags: permutations

I'm interested in the theory of calculating the position of an element when the face of a cube is moved - like in a Rubik's Cup. That is, for example, I rotate the face of the cube - how can I mathematically write down:

- all the displacements of its neighbors relative to each other
- the entire cube as a whole
- relative to a given point (tile) of the cube?

I am not a mathematician, but I was very interested in this question. Is there any particular area that studies this?

(Sorry for possible errors, I'm using a translator)

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for [group theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_theory).

Comment: Don't you mean Rubik's Cube ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let a small cube be centered at the coordinates $(x,y,z)$, where $x,y,z\in\{-1,0,1\}$. By a rotation of a quater turn around the $X$ axis, $(x,y,z)$ moves to $(x,-z,y)$. By composition, a rotation by a half turn goes to $(x,-y,-z)$ and so on. You can easily generalize to all three axis.

In the Rubik's Cube, a face has from one to three visible sides, which can be discriminated by a unit normal vector, such as $(u,v,z)$, where one of $u, v, w$ is $\pm1$ and the other components are $0$. The unit normals undergo the rotation following the same transformation. (E.g. $(0,1,0)$ to $(0,0,1)$.)

A rotation can thus be denoted as the product of a $3\times3$ matrix with two vectors. Rotations can be concatenated by multiplying the matrices. Beware that the rotations may no apply to all three slices simultaneously.

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&-1\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\-1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Alternatively, you can designate a normal as being in the direction of $X,Y$ or $Z$, with the sign being implicitly that of the corresponding component of the position. Hence $(1,1,1,Y)\to(1,-1,1,Z)$.